# How to upload file in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, upload

I want to save (upload) a file in silverlight into the silverlight application folder.

I get the URI of the application

```
string str3 = App.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri + "/Recording/";
```

but i don't know how to save file.

I use this code.....

```
        string extension = "wav";



        // Create an instance of the open file dialog box.
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter options and filter index.
        openFileDialog1.Filter = String.Format("{1} files (*.{0})|*.{0}|WAV FILES (*.*)|*.*", extension, "Audio");
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;

        // Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
        bool? userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        // Process input if the user clicked OK.
        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {

            string str = App.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri + "/Recording/";


            openFileDialog1.File.CopyTo(str);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work by itself (I assume your application is hosted on a web server), you need an uploader that will send the content to the server, and a server side handler that will receive and store the file.

Take you pick from one of those Silverlight uploaders:

[Silverlight File Uploader](http://silverlightuploader.codeplex.com/)
[Silverlight File Upload](http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/)
[Silverlight Multi File Uploader](http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/)

Personally I went with the first one, but I believe they're all quite good.

Comment: i want to to just load wav file and save in application folder..........

Have any other idea or code plz share it

Comment: What version of Silverlight are you using ? You may not have permissions to save to the application folder; have you tried to save it, say, to the destkop instead ?